# PostgreSQL - create a function that is using data from two columns to update another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a PostgreSQL function that will use the values from two columns - "column1" and "column2" - to update data in "column3".

The data in "column1" and "column2" already exists. I just need to use the data included in those two columns (with some kind of loop) to update "column3" (like "column1" space "column2").

All columns are part of the same table and they are VARCHAR. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses || for string concatenation (joining). So you can use a single update statement that will affect multiple rows at the same time

```
update tbl
set column3 = column1 || ' ' || column2
where ... (optional clause to identify records to update)
```

Comment: Do I just use the column1 and column2 names? How does it know I'm referring to the columns form the same table and not some other values?

Comment: It knows which table to update because you are writing `UPDATE tbl` - which specifies the table. You should really go through a good SQL tutorial first before proceeding any further. The one in the PostgreSQL manual is a good start.

Comment: To add to that, it is updating, for *each row* found (all, if not limited by the WHERE clause), the column3 value with the values of column1+space+column2 of the *same row*.

Comment: I was getting an error that's why I asked. I think the problem is related to something else.

Answer (score 2):

This will update column3 in all rows.

```
update your_table
set column3 = column1 || ' ' || column2
```